# The collection has changed. Possible inventory operation is not performed

Tags: c#, xna, collision

I am a beginner priogrammer and I got an game, where if sprites make a collision, they will get removed. But when I play it and the sprites make a collision I get this error: "The collection has changed. Possible inventory operation is not performed." (I translated this sentence from dutch to english). I dont really know how to solve this problem, any help is appreciated.

```
private void checkCollisions()
        {
            foreach (ISprite s in allSpriteBullets)
            {
                Rectangle kogel = new Rectangle((int)s.position.X, (int)s.position.Y, 10, 10);

                foreach (ISprite d in allSpriteObstakels) // error here
                {
                Rectangle blokjes = new Rectangle((int)d.position.X, (int)d.position.Y, 25, 25);
                Rectangle overlap = Rectangle.Intersect(kogel, blokjes);
                    if (!overlap.IsEmpty) 
                    {
                        if (s is Bullet)
                        {
                            d.CollisionWith(s);
                            s.CollisionWith(d);
                            hud.Score += 10;
                            allSpriteBullets.Remove(s);
                            allSpriteObstakels.Remove(d);
                        }

                        if (d is Monsters)
                        {
                            s.CollisionWith(d);
                            d.CollisionWith(s);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of using a for loop as opposed to a foreach to modify the collection.

```
List<SomeSprite> Sprites = new List<SomeSprite>();

//add items to the collection

for (int i = 0; i < Sprites.Count; ++i)
{
  SomeSprite Sprite = Sprites[i];
  if (SomeCondition == true) //determine if the sprite collided here
  {
    Sprites.RemoveAt(i);
    --i;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for giving this awnser, this really helps me out a lot

Comment: I updated it, it had a typo in it, Sprites[0] should have been Sprites[i].  Sprites[0] would always return the first sprite.

Comment: For loops can also be faster than foreach loops because for each loops are dependent on the collections Implementation of IEnumerable (e.g. some foreach faster than others).

Comment: It's wrong loop because if you remove item with index 'i' items count and all next indexes will less at 1. So if you use Sprites.Count in 'for' condition, you will iterate not Sprites.Count, but (Sprites.Count-removed_count) items. If you use some int count = Sprites.Count variable in 'for' condition you will get en error at (count-removed_count) index. Use for(int i = Sprites.Count-1, i>=0; i--) loop instead to avoid that problems.

Comment: Good pt Silveor, I forgot about that.

Comment: Updated to --i, Sprites.Count always returns the correct count int he list on each pass.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot modify collections while they are iterated i.e. in their own foreach-loop.

If you need to modify the collection, either use a for-loop or save the items to be removed in an extra collection and remove them when the foreach loop is done.